# Convert Projection Matrix to Realworld Matrix

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, arcore, projection-matrix

I'm using the following code to get the projection matrix from ARCore.

```
Frame.CameraImage.GetCameraProjectionMatrix(m_Camera.nearClipPlane, m_Camera.farClipPlane);
```

I would like to convert the Projection Matrix to World Matrix from the perspective of our eye. In other words, I'm trying to transform the ProjectionMatrix to that of the real world Matrix. Is there any possible solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

```
var camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
camera.projectionMatrix = Frame.CameraImage.GetCameraProjectionMatrix(camera.nearClipPlane, camera.farClipPlane);
var worldMatrix = camera.cameraToWorldMatrix;
```

`worldMatrix` is what you want I think.

Comment: I want to use the world matrix as a projection matrix as I'm trying to place the object aligned with the realworld dimension. Let me try this.

Comment: @user1241241 How do you set `worldMatrix` to another object?

Comment: `camera.projectionMatrix = Frame.CameraImage.GetCameraProjectionMatrix(camera.nearClipPlane, camera.farClipPlane).cameraToWorldMatrix;`

Comment: I used the above line of code to assign it back to the projection matrix